# Вставка json в mysql

Tags: json, php, mysql

Не получается вставить строку вида

```
$text = json_encode($string)
```

в базу данных в таблицу формата TEXT, постоянно вылетает ошибка
вставляю вот так

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table SET json=".$text.");
```

Answer (score 4):

Вы про квотирование чтото слышали ?

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table SET json='".mysql_real_escape_string($text)."'");
```

Answer (score 3):

Когда чутка подтяните свои знания, посмотрите что такое [`Prepared Statements`](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)